# Getting dict value from for loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

tl;dr:

I have a Scene class and scene01 and scene02, both instances of Scene. scene01 have a button.
This button is inside a dictionary named buttons, e.g. {button_next : scene02}

The for loop goes like this:

```
def loop(self):                                                         #SCENE LOOP
        while True:
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                    pg.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                    for k, v in self.buttons.items():
                        if 'click' in k.handleEvent(event):
                            self.goto(v)
            pg.display.update()
```

'click' in k.handleEvent(event) is from the PygButton widget. It return when there is a mouse click over the button. Button being an instance of the PygButton() class.

goto() checks if the value from the key-value pair is 'quit' (calling the app to quit) or an instance of Scene, e.g. scene01, calling the scene loop, drawing the new screen and new buttons.

The app starts, the first scene is there as is its buttons, but there is no response from a click on them. Escape quits the app so the loop is working. And exiting the app through the escape doesn't return anything from the IDLE.

I think the problem is on the goto() method and/or how I'm calling the value from the dictionary, but I'm stuck.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation seems off. Are you sure you want the second for loop to run only if the user quits because that is how you have set it up. Try this instead:

```
def loop(self):                                                         #SCENE LOOP
        while True:
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                    pg.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                for k, v in self.buttons.items():
                    if 'click' in k.handleEvent(event):
                        self.goto(v)
            pg.display.update()
```

Comment: Can't friggin believe this was the error. Guess coding way past midnight does this to people. Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: No problem. I just take a break if I am stuck on something for too long. Helps clear up some "prejudice" about the code I have written.